# isinstance() in dict comprehension

Tags: python

Working in an interactive mode, I input following assignments:

```
item = ['keys', 'values', 'items']
get = ['get', 'setdefault']
pop = ['pop', 'popitem']
copy = ['copy', 'fromkeys']
update = ['update']
clear = ['clear']
# my intent result
{'item': ['keys', 'values', 'items'],
'get': ['get', 'setdefault'],
'pop': ['pop', 'popitem'],
'copy': ['copy', 'fromkeys'],
'update': ['update'],
'clear': ['clear']}}
```

I intend to fetch a dict of them from `locals()`with a dict comprehension and type checking.

```
>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'item': ['keys', 'values', 'items'], 'get': ['get', 'setdefault'], 'pop': ['pop', 'popitem'], 'copy': ['copy', 'fromkeys'], 'update': ['update'], 'clear': ['clear']}
```

my code:

```
{k:v for k, v in locals().items if isinstance(v, list)}
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

I fixed it

```
In [12]: {k:locals[k] for k in locals() if isinstance(locals()[k], list)}
#Error reports again.
KeyError: '__name__'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I wish you would find some other way than doing this. Why not put these into dicts as the lists are created? What if your environment has 10 other lists that are not relevant to the dictionary you are trying to create?

Comment: +1 to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's comment. Accessing these inputs from `locals` doesn't seem to be a good idea. If you explain why you're doing it this way, someone might be able to offer a different / better approach.

Comment: bug marked: `items` to `items()`

Comment: get your idea @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: If put them into dict, I have to add ' ' to each key. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @DeFu Is that a problem?

Comment: too much work for ring and little finger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling the method `items()` :

```
{k:v for k, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, list)}
```

EDIT:
Using locals() like this sounds like an ugly hack, it's OK to use it in interactive mode, to discover how python store its variable, but it is definitively not a good idea to use it in "real code". If you need to store those parameters together, think about a class for example :

```
class MyKeywords:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = ['keys', 'values', 'items']
        self.get = ['get', 'setdefault']
        self.pop = ['pop', 'popitem']
        self.copy = ['copy', 'fromkeys']
        self.update = ['update']
        self.clear = ['clear']
```

or find another way to get/store them, locals is definitively not made for this :)

Comment: While your answer might address the question at its face, it skips the underlying problem which is the OP stirring up a pot of smelly code by using `locals` in the first place.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you're right, using locals is a bad idea, but, the problem OP was facing to is not directly related to the use of locals (which is bad :) ), but most of list comprehensions. I'll add a warning in my answer :)

Comment: ty for the tuturial